# Check objects inside an array to see if any contain a substring? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm using the Express framework in Node.js. The user fills out a form and submits it where the form data is stored as an object with a property for each field into an array. The user can then go to a query page that has a single text field to search all form entries by entering a substring and all form entries that contain that substring in any of their fields will be listed.

Here is a snippet from my **index.js:**

```
router.post('/doquery', function(req, res) {
    var inp = { input: req.body.input };
    var tempState = [];

    for (var obj in state) {
        for (var prop in obj) {
            for (var input in inp) {
                if (prop.indexOf(input) !== -1) {
                    tempState.push(obj);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    res.render('list', { title: 'People Listing',  items: tempState});
});
```

`inp` is the object holding the substring. What I want to do is search through the array of form entry objects and if an object contains the `"inp"` substring in any of it's properties then add it to tempState and display all objects in `tempState` on the list page. `state` is a global array which its elements are objects holding each separate form entry.

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: if you can show the arrayy of form elements ?

Comment: `for in` loops enumerate the **property names**, not the property values of your objects. `obj` will be a string.